# Spring Boot Kerberos and Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, webpack, kerberos

I have implemented and deployed **Spring Boot** services that are accessible through **Kerberos**. Authentication is properly done when testing from any machine which is part of the domain thanks to curl:

`curl uri --negociate -u myuser`

Unfortunately, when testing the Angular Client that I have implemented for that purpose, Chrome doesn't negociate the authentication. Actually, it doesn't send any Kerberos token (although it does with other applications) when receiving the first www-Authenticate response.

Spring boot then interprets the request as an Anonymous Connexion.

Is there any configuration I have to do on my webpack-dev-server or Angular-side to make the authentication working?

home.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.http.get(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/account');
 ... }
```

webpack.dev.js:

```
module.exports = (options) => webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './target/classes/static/',
        proxy: [{
            context: [
                '/api'
            ],
            target: process.env.SERVER_API_URL,
            secure: false,
            ignorePath: true,
            changeOrigin: true
        }],
```

Comment: Try to add `withCredentials: true` flag to all `HttpClient` requests.

Comment: Thanks @KarolTrybulec, this has solved my problem.